# Marlin Firmware Manual Mesh Leveling

Tags: marlin

Why am I seeing two different versions of the way to enable manual leveling?

One option says to enable:

```
#define manual_bed_leveling
#define mesh_bed_leveling
```

And the other says to enable:

```
#define probe_manually
#define LCD_bed_leveling
#define mesh_bed_leveling
```

How is it that they both work? One is from the official marlin github and the other is from a tutorial that is confirmed to work.

Comment: Which revision of Marlin are you working with?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Good one, clearly not the latest source!

Comment: I am using the latest non beta ................................................................................................................................................... I now realize that this tutorial from the github wiki (which lists no version #) is old. I would have thought they would have updated it seeing as how it is the official repo for Marlin.

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the most recent version of Marlin you will find in file [`Marlin/SanityCheck.h`](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/85c82ab28e13cb25043ae166062785bff39434b9/Marlin/SanityCheck.h):

```
elif defined(MANUAL_BED_LEVELING)
  #error "MANUAL_BED_LEVELING is now LCD_BED_LEVELING. Please update your configuration."
```

This implies that constant `MANUAL_BED_LEVELING` is obsolete. It is not found anywhere else except for the file linked above. So, **no**, the constants are not supposed to do exactly the same. Instead an error is shown on compiling to update your configuration to exclude the constant `MANUAL_BED_LEVELING`.